# Force DB Schema Update

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, database, upgrade

Is there a way to trigger a DB schema update?

I've just copied the live DB which is 1.8 to a development host which has 1.9.3.3 installed. The frontend is displaying correctly but I can't get into /admin as some of the metadata tables are missing columns.

For example I'm getting the following logged in `var/report`

> a:5:{i:0;s:698:"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly.product_type_id' in 'field list', query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT MAX(DATE_FORMAT(period, '%Y-%m-%d')) AS `period`, SUM(qty_ordered) AS `qty_ordered`, `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly`.`product_id`, MAX(product_name) AS `product_name`, MAX(product_price) AS `product_price`, `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly`.`product_type_id` FROM `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly` WHERE (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `existed_products` WHERE (sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly.product_id = existed_products.entity_id))) AND (store_id IN(0)) GROUP BY `product_id` LIMIT 5) AS `t`";i:1;s:5064:"#0 /public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved my issue using `n98-magerun sys:setup:incremental` this ran through the update scripts.

Comment: n98-magerun is indeed a live saving tool, a must have for Magento.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting your local.xml and do installation again.